# How to remove type error when assigning PKPushRegistryDelegate for Pushkit?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, callkit, pushkit

I'm trying to create a VOIP calling application, but getting a "Cannot assign value of 'CallDelegate.Type'to 'PKPushRegistryDelegate.

Below is my delegate class. The class inherits PKPushRegistryDelegate and implements the pushRegistry methods. Not in AppDelegate because I need the Init method to init the CallKit CXProvider (same error, if you put everything in AppDelegate though).

```
import Foundation
import CallKit
import PushKit

class CallDelegate : NSObject, PKPushRegistryDelegate
{
    private let provider: CXProvider        

    static func registerVoIPPush() {
        let voipPushResgistry = PKPushRegistry(queue: DispatchQueue.main)

        voipPushResgistry.delegate = self //**Getting the assign error here**

        voipPushResgistry.desiredPushTypes = [PKPushType.voIP]            
    }

    func pushRegistry( _ registry: PKPushRegistry, didUpdate credentials: PKPushCredentials, for type: PKPushType) {
        if type == PKPushType.voIP {                
            let tokenData = credentials.token                
            let voipPushToken = String(data: tokenData, encoding: .utf8)

            //Send the POST request to oneSignal here
        }
    }

    func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType) {
        if type == .voIP {

            if let handle = payload.dictionaryPayload["handle"] as? String,
                let uuidString = payload.dictionaryPayload["uuid"] as? String,
                let isVideo = payload.dictionaryPayload["isVideo"] as? Bool {

                reportInComingCallWith(uuidString: uuidString, handle: handle, isVideo: isVideo)
            }
        }
    }


    func pushRegistry( _ registry: PKPushRegistry, didInvalidatePushTokenFor type: PKPushType) {            
    }

    func pushRegistry( _ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type:PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {            
        if type == PKPushType.voIP {                
        }
    }
```

I've enabled VOIP notifications in capabilities and linked the Pushkit framework to the project. Targeting IOS 13. A lot of things in the documentation don't work out of the box (deprecated methods, names, etc), maybe the registry assigning got changed as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `registerVoIPPush()` method is static, hence in that context `self` refers to the type and not to an instance of `CallDelegate`. You have to assign an instance of your `CallDelegate` class to the `PKPushRegistry` delegate.

Comment: Hello can you please explain that in detail? I am facing the same error.